# Geonetwork 2.10.4: Whitelist www.example.com/geonetwork/monitor/ for load balancer

Tags: geonetwork, tomcat

I want to monitor my Geonetwork 2.10.4 from the load balancer with the URL www.example.com/geonetwork/monitor/healthcheck (slow) or www.example.com/geonetwork/criticalhealthcheck (fast). When I access these URLs, I need to log in. The load balancer cannot do this. Therefore I want to whitelist the URLs for the load balancer.

The documentation of Geonetwork 2.10.4 contains the following text.

> "By default the /monitor/* urls are protected and may only be accessed by an ‘’administrator” or ‘’monitor’‘, however it is possible in the web.xml to provide a whitelist of URLs or IP addresses of monitoring servers that are permitted to access the monitoring data without needing an administration account."

Unfortunately, it doesn't say how to do that.

Removing/commenting the following text from `web.xml`

```
<!-- Only allow administrators or localhost access to the monitoring metrics -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>MetricsRegistryInitializerFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.fao.geonet.monitor.webapp.MetricsRegistryInitializerFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

results in the Tomcat error

```
Jul 18, 2018 12:00:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/geonetwork]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Filter mapping specifies an unknown filter name MetricsRegistryInitializerFilter
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.validateFilterMap(StandardContext.java:3111)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addFilterMap(StandardContext.java:3076)
        at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1265)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1331)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:863)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:371)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5401)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more

Jul 18, 2018 12:00:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geonetwork.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/geonetwork]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

https://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/2.10.4/eng/users/admin/monitoring/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a line from a previous version, `2.8.x` where you could configure this filter in `web.xml`.

```
<!-- Only allow administrators or localhost access to the monitoring metrics -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>MonitorSecurityFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.fao.geonet.monitor.MonitorSecurityFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
         <!--
         White-list is comma seperated list of trusted source that can call monitor.
         For example nagios server -->
        <param-name>white-list</param-name>
        <param-value>localhost</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

...

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MonitorSecurityFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/monitor/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Unfortunately `MonitorSecurityFilter` is not available in `2.10.x` anymore since it has been removed in favor of Spring Security. In `2.10.4` you will need to modify some rules in [config-security-mapping.xml](https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/blob/2.10.4/web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/config-security-mapping.xml#L14-L16) from

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/monitor/.*" access="hasRole('Monitor')"></sec:intercept-url>
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/monitor" access="hasRole('Monitor')"></sec:intercept-url>
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/\w*healthcheck" access="hasRole('Monitor')"></sec:intercept-url>
```

to

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/monitor/.*" access="permitAll"></sec:intercept-url>
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/monitor" access="permitAll"></sec:intercept-url>
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/\w*healthcheck" access="permitAll"></sec:intercept-url>
```

If you want to allow specific hosts you could use Spring Security's [Web Security Expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#el-access-web), for example

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/monitor/.*" access="hasIpAddress('192.168.1.0/24')"></sec:intercept-url>
```

Comment: LGTM. :) YMMD. :)